# Show that the "Hartogs Regularity Radius" $R(z)$ is subharmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

**Exercise**

I'm a little stuck on an Exercise in *Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables* by R. Michael Range. The Exercise (E.II.5.1) is as follows (here $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is the family of holomorphic functions on $D$):

> Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ and suppose $f_{v}\in\mathcal{O}(D)$ for $v=0,1,2,\ldots$. Define the *Hartogs regularity radius* $R(z)$ of the series
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum_{v=0}^{\infty}f_{v}(z)w^{v}, w\in\mathbb{C},
> \end{equation}
>   by setting $R(z)$ equal to the radius of convergence of the above in $w$. Prove that $-\log R(z)$ is subharmonic on $D$. (This is fundamental result of Hartogs, which is at the core of Oka's Theorem 5.6.)

**My attempt**

Note that, explicitly,
$$
R(z)=\frac{1}{\limsup_{v\to\infty}\sqrt[v]{|f_{v}(z)|}}
$$
so
\begin{equation}
-\log R(z)=\log\left(\limsup_{v\to\infty}\sqrt[v]{|f_v(z)|}\right).
\end{equation}
Let $\{v_j\}$ be a subsequence such that
$$
\lim_{j\to\infty}\sqrt[v_j]{|f_{v_j}(z)|}=\limsup_{v\to\infty}\sqrt[v]{|f_{v}(z)|}
$$
and define a sequence
$$
u_j(z):=\log\left(|f_{v_j}(z)|^{1/v_j}\right).
$$
Clearly $\lim_{j\to\infty}u=-\log R(z)$, and (as has been shown) each $\log|f_{v_j}(z)|$ is subharmonic. Hence each
$
u_j(z)=\tfrac{1}{v_j}\log |f_{v_j}|
$
is subharmonic.

From here, I would like this show that this implies the limit function is subharmonic, but I don't know how to go about it. One way I know could do it by showing the sequence $\{u_j\}$ is decreasing, but I don't believe this is the case.

Also, this is the first exercise in the set for this section, so I feel as though there might be a significantly easier way. If anyone has any hints/tips on how to repair this argument or possibly have an idea on a simpler one, it would be a huge help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whait is $O(D)?$

Comment: @zhw. The space of holomorphic functions on $D$. It should be stated at the top of the question

Comment: Yes you did, I missed it. Thanks

Comment: What if $f_n(z) = e^{n^2 z}$ in the open unit disc? Doesn't that give $+\infty$ as a value for $-\log R(z)$ here, and isn't that illegal for a subharmonic function?

Comment: @zhw. Hmm that seems like a proper counterexample. Perhaps the author intended the statement to only apply to those sequences of holomorphic functions which correspond to a nonzero radius of convergence?

I think I recall this bothering me when I originally encountered this problem now that you mention it.